# how i can tell glassfish about my spring dependancy injection?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, glassfish, server

I am new here, I am working on a project using hibernate and spring dependency injection and SOAP web service.

My problem is when I run my project in the console using this class:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");
    IServicesPharmacie pharmacieService = (IServicesPharmacie) context.getBean("service");
    context.close();
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:3597/Pharmacies", pharmacieService);
    System.out.println("The service has been published with success!");
```

my project work fine, because with these 3 lines:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");
    IServicesPharmacie pharmacieService = (IServicesPharmacie) context.getBean("service");
    context.close();
```

I can tell about my spring dependancy injection.

BUT i don't know how to run my project on a glassfish server, and tell him about my spring dependancy injection, I guess that I most have a web.xml!!!!

My spring-beans.xml is like that :

```
<bean class="dao.PharmImpl" id="dao"></bean>

<bean class="metier.PharMetier" id="metier">
    <property name="phardao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="services.ServicesPharmacie" id="service">
    <property name="servmetier" ref="metier" />
        </bean>
 </beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) to bootstrap spring in your application. like below:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Perhaps if you are using springMVC its done as below:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please note URL-pattern is based on your requirement.